# find a directory and opening it in Windows with cmd

Tags: windows-7, batch-file, cmd.exe

is there possibly any way to find the directory of a file ("example.txt") and then if it finds the file open the directory (such as "c:\example\sub\") on cmd (or vb)? of course looking in all the partitions not just "C:\".

Comment: The first part of your question is clear and I think I have a solution to it below. I'm not sure what you meant in the second part though -- "then if it finds the file open the directory"? Could you rephrase that?

Comment: I just meant that when the file is found I'd like that the folder where the file is located opens up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run the following command from the root of each of your drives.

```
for /f "delims=" %a in ('dir /s /b example.txt') do explorer %~dpa
```

The above command will find all files named "example.txt" and then run explorer in the directory wehere they are located.

If you wish to use a batch file then each `%` needs to be replaced by `%%`:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /s /b example.txt') do explorer %%~dpa
```

To get a list of drives:

```
for /f "skip=1 delims=" %a in ('wmic logicaldisk get caption') do @echo %a
```

In a batch file:

```
for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%a in ('wmic logicaldisk get caption') do @echo %%a
```

Putting it all together in a batch file:

```
for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%a in ('wmic logicaldisk get caption') do (
    cd %%a
    cd \
    for /f "delims=" %%b in ('dir /s /b example.txt') do explorer %%~dpb
)
```

To stop after the first match:

```
for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%a in ('wmic logicaldisk get caption') do (
    cd %%a
    cd \
    for /f "delims=" %%b in ('dir /s /b example.txt') do (
        explorer %%~dpb
        exit
    )
)
```

Comment: This work thank you, how do I make it work in a batch file? I tried but it only work in the command prompt window, also how do I make it search for every drive?

Comment: although the code in some case is opening one folder back that the folder where a file is located: if I'm looking for "example.txt" that is in folder3 ("D:\folder1\folder2\folder3"), in some cases opens the folder2, but in other cases it works, how this can be solved?

Comment: (C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Portable Devices\wpdlog02.sqm) - (C:\Users\Matt\Desktop\WALLS\wall1.png) - (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft XNA\XNA Game Studio\v4.0\Redist\DX Redist\APR2007_d3dx9_33_x86.rar) (C:\ProgramData\Adobe\Adobe PDF\Extras\MAGAZINE Ad 2006 JPN.joboptions), I tried with those paths to test the code and they won't work.

Comment: did you replace example.txt with the complete path or just the filename? Some of the filename have spaces. Thenb you probably need " around them eg dir /s /b "example with space.txt"

Comment: @powerofwheels replacing `example.txt` with `wpdlog02.sqm` works as expected for me. opening explorer in directory `C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Portable Devices\` and terminating the batch file.

Comment: For me is not actually working, I ran the batch in both C: and D:  drives (as administrator too) to find the file "example1.txt" located in C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Portable Devices and it says "file not found"

Comment: Then I'm stuck. You might find this of help to see what is happening on your system [Debugging your batch files](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_debugging.php). I would start by putting some echo %% whatever in the batch file you are actually using.

Answer (score 0):

This will locate all files with the given extensions in the current working directory and all subdirectories:

`dir *.cpp *.h *.java /b/s`

This will do it for files beginning with "pyth"

`dir pyth*`

you can extend this example.

To open the file location (i.e. the folder) you can `cd` to the result and type either

`explorer .`

or

`start .`

If you don't want to use `cd` then you can pass the file location from `dir` to the `explorer` or `start` command.

To adapt this into a for-loop for each mounted drive check out this Stackoverflow post:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5709189/batch-script-to-find-drive-letter-of-a-mounted-device

Comment: This find the file but yet not open the directory where is located the file.

Comment: @powerofwheels Thanks for the clarification; I've updated the solution.

Comment: "If you don't want to use cd then you can pass the file location from dir to the explorer or start command." How do I pass this information?

Comment: If I want to find the "example.txt" file in the D: drive, and then pass this information to explorer; how'd the code be like for a batch file? Also, there is a way to make it search for each drive?

Comment: @powerofwheels This should give you what you need to do a for loop in a batch file for each drive: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5709189/batch-script-to-find-drive-letter-of-a-mounted-device

Comment: @powerofwheels You're very welcome